# Spare area on screen

Tags: windows-7

Is there a possibility to spare an area of the screen so that if an applications window is maximized, the window doesn't use the full screen area.
I'm looking for the same behaviour as the task-bar has. With default-settings, application windows do not overlap the area of the task-bar (except in full-screen mode). I would like to spare some space on the left and on the right on of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Desktop Coral](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/index.html) does exactly what you describe. I use it on one of my machines to reserve a space at the top for system information.

It is very configurable and easy to use.